# Иерархия команд в телеграм боте

Tags: python, aiogram

Всем привет! Обратился я сюда с проблемой по созданию бота в телеграм используя aiogram. Перейдем к сути, я хочу создать бота по типу велком листа или что то типо того, в моем боте должна быть иерархия команд, в которой нельзя обратиться к команде если ты не находишься на определенном уровне иерархии. Я думал использовать машину состояний, но мне я не уверен что делаю все правильно по этому и обратился сюда. К этой теме я прикрепил сообщений с примерной структурой моего бота, а теперь перейдем к вопросам:

1. Как сделать ветвление состояний (Столовая > Меню/Персонал/График_работы; Меню > Товар > Название, ..., ...)
2. При отправке файла по телеграму он записывается на сервер, где потом уже можно не скачивая файл отправить его по ID и тут вопрос - Как долго хранится файл на серверах телеграм и есть ли какие либо ограничения по количеству использований этого ID?
3. В админке бота есть команды по изменению и добавлению данных в бд, где я постоянно использую if с проверкой ID админа, можно ли как-то оптимизировать это используя функцию?
4. Как принимать от администратора pdf файл и скачивать его на сервер?
5. Можно ли создавать несколько классов состояний, а после проверять в одном хендлере наличие сразу двух состояний?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Если не уверен значит разбей задачи на более мелкие. Через FSM самый простой и адекватный вариант. У тебя даже схема и понимание есть.....

3. Можно, уже были вроде такие вопросы.
4. Сделать функцию которая это будет делать и сохранять в бд.
5. Да. (Привет FSM)